# React MUI DataGrid pagination not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I have a datagrid:

```
const handlePageChange = (newOffset, newLimit) => {
    setOffset(newOffset);
  };

      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        className="grid-container"
        columns={columns}
        hideFooter={rows?.length < 5}
        initialState={{
          pagination: {
            paginationModel: { pageSize: 5, page: 0 },
          },
        }}
        pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
        autoHeight={false}
        autoWidth={false}
        {...rest}
        localeText={{
          noRowsLabel: (
            <Typography variant="h5" component={"h2"} fontWeight={"normal"}>
              No Data
            </Typography>
          ),
        }}
        onPaginationModelChange={(params) => {
          const newOffset = rows?.length + 1;
           handlePageChange(newOffset);
         }}
        slots={{
          toolbar: toolbar,
        }}
        loading={isLoading}
      />
```

Here I want to do the server side pagination. I have used a limit as 5. By this, I mean only 5 objects should be returned from the backend. I have also a variable called as offset which I need to send it to the backend that from which index next set of data should come.

So I added:

```
const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
```

for the first instance. Then once user clicks on the next then I am adding the length of the previous result into it . So that it becomes the 5 likewise.

But this way it is not working and when I click back also it does not work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more parameter to the DataGrid component, which is
**paginationModel**
paginationModel must be an object which has two keys:

```
{ pageSize: 5, page: current_page }
```

depending on your backend data, change the **page** in **paginationModel** accordingly.